# How to change PHP version in Mac OSX El Capitan?

Tags: php, osx-elcapitan

I'm using a MAMP setup in Mac OS 10.11.5 (El Capitan). This works fine for web server purposes, but when I try to use the PHP CLI, Terminal uses the system version:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

From everything I've found and read, it seems like the solution is to add the MAMP version to my `PATH`:

```
PATH="$HOME/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH"
```

However, after adding this, closing and re-opening the window, and sourcing the file, Terminal still doesn't find the version I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a gist for this https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693

```
Within the Terminal, run vim ~/.bash_profile

Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH

Hit ESC, Type :wq, and hit Enter

In Terminal, run source ~/.bash_profile

In Terminal, type in which php again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).
```

Comment: Thanks. I've followed all of these steps already and the version still does not change.

Comment: Following the above directions work for me now in MacOS X 10.12 Sierra